# capturing row click in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in HTML where I have a radio button at the end of each row. This is for example:

```
<form name="summary_form" method="post" action="">
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
        <tr>
            <td width="15%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Start Date</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="7%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Seq#</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Position</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Location</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Department</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="15%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Salary/Hourly Rate</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td height="29" bgcolor="#999999">
                <div align="center"><font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#993300"><b><font color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</font> 
                    </b>
                    </font>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="10">10/24/2008</div>
            </td>
            <td width="7%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">01</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="20">O035 - Security Guard</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="40">040 - Kingston</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">5000 - GUARD WAGES-OPERATIONS</div>
            </td>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="55">10.2000</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="employeeid_key1" value="5763" />
                <input type="hidden" name="posstartdate_key1" value="2008-10-24 00:00:01.0" />
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="radio" value="1" name="R" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="10">10/24/2008</div>
            </td>
            <td width="7%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">00</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="20">O035 - Security Guard</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="40">040 - Kingston</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">5000 - GUARD WAGES-OPERATIONS</div>
            </td>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="55">10.2000</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="employeeid_key2" value="5763" />
                <input type="hidden" name="posstartdate_key2" value="2008-10-24 00:00:00.0" />
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="radio" value="2" name="R" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="10">04/21/1998</div>
            </td>
            <td width="7%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">01</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="20">O035 - Security Guard</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="40">040 - Kingston</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">5000 - GUARD WAGES-OPERATIONS</div>
            </td>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="55">7.6000</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="employeeid_key1" value="5763" />
                <input type="hidden" name="posstartdate_key1" value="1998-04-21 00:00:00.0" />
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="radio" value="3" name="R" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="rows" value="3" />
</form>
<form id="keys_form" name="keys_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="employeeid_key" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="posstartdate_key" value="" />
</form>
```

To perform an action on a specific row, user first select that row by clicking on the radio button of that row; and then perform the action.

To get the current row selected, we use this javascript function:

```
function getCurrentRow() {
    var rows = parseInt(document.summary_form.rows.value);
    var row = 0;
    if (rows > 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            if (document.summary_form.R[i].checked) {
                row = document.summary_form.R[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (rows == 1) {
        if (document.summary_form.R.checked) row = 1;
    }
    return row;
}
```

What I want is to get rid of the radio buttons and instead capture the event when user click on any row. Fellow developer thinks its not possible with html `table` and only possible with `div` using `onclick` event of `div` which means each row will have its own `div`. I want to use table if possible. How can I capture row click in html table?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: _“Fellow developer thinks its not possible with html table and only possible with div”_ – fellow developer doesn’t seem to know what they are talking about. If I were you, I would go read up on some basics, and prove them wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I am not much into client-side stuff. May be he was thinking about adding event listeners to the `div` which I presume is not possible with `tr` of `table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pure Javascript, you can try something like shown in the following code snippet:

```
// ** add table row click event 
function row_OnClick(tblId) {
    try {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var _row = rows[i];
            _row.onclick = function () {
                return function () {
                    // YOUR CODE HERE
                };
            }(_row);
        }
    }
        catch (err) { }
    }
```

where table is passed to the function by its id (tblId). The usage is rather straightforward: for e.g. call this function from page body `onload` event. Practical implementation could be found in: http://infosoft.biz/bus.aspx (row is selected on click; also, double-click event handle is added to table rows in a similar way, performing the app-specific functions). The solution could be also implemented with jQuery, but it will require additional jQuery library.

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? Is the function `row_OnClick(tblId)` called after page is loaded say from `onLoad` of body? Can you give me a JSFiddle? If a pure JavaScript solution works then I will go with it.

Comment: You can use onload event. Practical implementation is here (click on any row to get it selected): http://infosoft.biz/bus.aspx. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to give every `tr` an `id` and use `jquery` event to determine which `tr` was clicked, i.e:

```js
$("body").click(function(event){
  target = $(event.target);
  if ( target.parent().is( "td" ) ) {
    var trId = $(target.closest("tr")).attr( "id" );
    alert( trId );
      //do something with trId, a switch statement perhaps?
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
        <tr>
            <td width="15%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Start Date</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="7%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Seq#</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Position</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Location</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Department</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td width="15%" height="29" bgcolor="#999999"> <b><p  align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  size="1" color="#FFFFFF" > Salary/Hourly Rate</font></p></b>

            </td>
            <td height="29" bgcolor="#999999">
                <div align="center"><font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#993300"><b><font color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</font> 
                    </b>
                    </font>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="td01">
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="10">10/24/2008</div>
            </td>
            <td width="7%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">01</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="20">O035 - Security Guard</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="40">040 - Kingston</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">5000 - GUARD WAGES-OPERATIONS</div>
            </td>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="55">10.2000</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="td02">
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="10">10/24/2008</div>
            </td>
            <td width="7%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">00</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="20">O035 - Security Guard</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="40">040 - Kingston</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">5000 - GUARD WAGES-OPERATIONS</div>
            </td>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="55">10.2000</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="employeeid_key2" value="5763" />
                <input type="hidden" name="posstartdate_key2" value="2008-10-24 00:00:00.0" />
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="radio" value="2" name="R" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="td03">
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="10">04/21/1998</div>
            </td>
            <td width="7%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">01</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="20">O035 - Security Guard</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;" tabindex="40">040 - Kingston</div>
            </td>
            <td width="25%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="45">5000 - GUARD WAGES-OPERATIONS</div>
            </td>
            <td width="15%" height="29" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt">
                <div align="center" style=" font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" tabindex="55">7.6000</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="employeeid_key1" value="5763" />
                <input type="hidden" name="posstartdate_key1" value="1998-04-21 00:00:00.0" />
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="radio" value="3" name="R" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="rows" value="3" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But your solution does not work if I click on white space above or below the text in a cell. For example in 1st row in **Seq#** column, if I click on white space above `01` or on white space below `01`, then the click event is not captured. Can you fix this issue?

Comment: I'll try to help you when I arrive home.